# ngCordovaOauth not working on IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Project

Tags: oauth, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, ngcordova

I have tried [ngCordovaOauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) on my ionic project, it is running well.

But when i tried to move the project to my IBM MobileFirst 7.1, the error occured :

```
   chromium(18431): [INFO:CONSOLE(25644)] "TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Function.keys (native)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Object.b [as isInAppBrowserInstalled] (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js:6:12474)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Object.d [as google] (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js:5:12292)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Scope.service.ngCordovaGoogleLogin [as loginNgCordova] (file:///android_asset/www/default/js/app.js:106:23)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at fn (eval at <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:26459:15), <anonymous>:4:233)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62388:9
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Scope.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29160:28)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at Scope.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:29259:23)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:62387:13)
03-18 12:02:43.154: I/chromium(18431):     at HTMLButtonElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (file:///android_asset/www/default/worklight/wljq.js:3140:9)", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (25644)
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that ngCordovaOauth requires a different Cordova versions; In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 the Cordova version is 3.6.4;

Also need to understand why you are attempting to use a different OAuth than the implementation supplied by MFP; other such implementations will not work with the MobileFirst Server, unless what you are trying to do is outside of the MFP scope...